# Android Navigation And Gradle 7.3.3 namespace Kapt Plugin Generated Directions Fail To Resolve Resources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, package-name

Since the new Android Studio [Version "Chipmunk"](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/05/android-studio-chipmunk.html) the Gradle update helper suggests that you remove the `package` keyword from the `AndroidManifest.xml` and instead use a object `namespace` in the `android` block inside the app-level `build.gradle`.

However, using the recent version `2.4.2` and also with the version `2.5.0-rc01` of the standard navigation library, the Directions generated by the kapt plugin no longer import the correct resource path when a different `applicationId` is set for a build flavor.

For example if my default package name is `my.package.com` and I have a flavor called `dev` which is declared with a `applicationId` "my.package.com.dev" and the `namespace` is set to `my.package.com`, the generated directions all throw build errors: `Unresolved reference: R`.

Has anyone else stumbled over this issue and is there anything we can do to fix this?

I had to remove the `namespace` and put back in the `package` parameter in my `AndroidManifest` to resolve this issue, but that doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Indicate [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233119646) that you are affected by this issue

Comment: I did, thanks for letting me know that there is an issue open.

Answer (score 6):

I've just noted that this is a reported issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232107688). So adding back package name in manifest resolved the issue for the time being for my self.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.myapp.gcapp"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple modules in my app and had to add namespace to each module's build.gradle file.